# Swift 3: how to change the button image in UITableView?

Tags: swift

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   ...

 let doLikeBtn = detailCell.contentView.viewWithTag(106) as! UIButton
                doLikeBtn.setTitle(String(indexPath.row), for: UIControlState.normal)
                doLikeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doLike(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

...

 }

...

 func doLike(sender: UIButton) {
        selectUserIndex = sender.title(for: UIControlState.normal)!

    if sender.image(for: UIControlState.normal) == UIImage(named: "btn_Like.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_not_Like.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_Like.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
 }
```

If I click one button in table, and then change the image of button, but other some button's images also are changed repeatedly.
I can't understand this.
Please help me!
Best regards.

Comment: When a button scrolls off the the screen it is saved and reused when another cell scrolls into view. Cell content is not reset automatically so you have to set the default image when you create the cell in `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Thank you!
I added a line;
doLikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_ok"), for: UIControlState.normal)
So other button images are not changed.
But the target button image is changed to original image after scrolling.
Could you help me more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is for performance reasons,
>   you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to
>   content.

So you need to update your cell every time cellForRowAt invoked:

also you need to keep track of which cell getting "liked or dislike" so you can add for example a boolean isLike property to YourCustomCell
and toggle it true or false upon doLike func triggered

```
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.deque... as! YourCustomCell

                if cell.isLiked == false {
                        cell.btnSomething.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_not_Like.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                    }else {
                        cell.btnSomething.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_Like.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                    }

                }
```

Comment: just I am update the code, please make sure to keep track of the state of your cell "like status"  it's one of best practises

Comment: Thank a lot!
It's very useful for me!
I am developing some swift apps, please help me in the future...

Answer (score 0):

> Updated for Swift 3/4:

*Use lines of code to change/set the UIButton Image in UITableView;*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourTableViewCellStoryboardIdentifier")! as! YourTableViewCellName

        if status == 1{
            cell.mStatusButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "pending_icon"), for: .normal)
        }else if status == 2{
            cell.mStatusButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "approval"), for: .normal)
        }else if status == 3{
            cell.mStatusButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "reject_icon"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            cell.mStatusButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "cancle"), for: .normal)
        }

    return cell
}
```

**Note: where mStatusButtonOutlet - is your UIButtonOutlet**

Enjoy..!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4, Below is a simple way to do it

```
class AddressTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var starButton: UIButton!
    var buttonObject : (() -> Void)? = nil
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if let buttonAction = self.buttonObject {
            buttonAction()
        }
    }
}

 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addressTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
    cell.buttonObject = {
        if cell.starButton.currentImage == UIImage(named: "fav") {
            cell.starButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "favYellow"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            cell.starButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "fav"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```